# JavaScript date comparison gives invalid time value when month is oct, nov, des

Tags: javascript, date

I made this code to compare two locale dates regardless of browser and device time, to be used as a display of Swedish local music events/ticket sale. The code works when the input `date_string` is equal to jan-sept, if the `date_string` is equal to okt-des (month 10-12) I get an `Invalid time value`

**How can I make this code work if `const date_string = "27. desember, 2019";` ?**

```js
       //const date_string = "27. september, 2019"; // This works
       const date_string = "27. desember, 2019"; // This does not Work! Why?

       const newDateOptions = {
          year: "numeric",
          month: "long",
          day: "numeric",
        };
        
        const today = new Date();
        const today_utc = Date.UTC(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
        const today_string = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("sv-SE", newDateOptions).format(today);
        
        const test_date = new Date(date_string);
        const test_date_utc = Date.UTC(test_date.getFullYear(), test_date.getMonth(), test_date.getDate());
        const test_date_string = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("sv-SE", newDateOptions).format(test_date);
        
        console.log("Today's date: " + today_string);
        
        if (test_date_utc > today_utc) {
          console.log(test_date_string + " is a Future Date");
        } else {
          console.log(test_date_string + " is a Past Date");
        }
```

Comment: Does `Desember` need to be changed to `December`?

Comment: yea in copying it to a snippet correcting that typo yields an answer rather than an error. Tried October and November those work as well.

Comment: Just double checked. If you run these two lines to verify: `console.log(new Date("27. desember, 2019"));` and `console.log(new Date("27. december, 2019"));` you'll see a message in the console "Invalid Date" for the first log, and the proper date you're looking for in the second log.

Answer (score 0):

If you change Desember to December, it should work